# Selenium method WaitUntilTextToBePresentInElement fails

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I have label with text changed from `MQL` to `SQL` value.

```
<label for="stage_label" id="Stage_label"><div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible">Stage SQL</div>SQL<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></label>
```

I need to wait until label contains 'SQL' value.

If I use Selenium native wait method my test fails in 30 seconds with TimedoutException

```
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(driver.FindElement(
    By.Id("Stage_label")), "SQL"));
```

At the same time if I try to debug and check element text it successfully returns SQL after some time of waiting

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(
         By.Id("Stage_label")).Text);
         Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
```

`MQL MQL MQL SQL SQL`

Why Selenium method doesn't work in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by it fails? does it throws `NoSuchElementException` or `TimedoutException` ?

Comment: It throws "Timed out after 30 seconds" exception

Comment: Is it possible the entire element is being destroyed and recreated? With your test add a variable to get the element before the loop and just grab the text on that instead of getting the element new every time. That will tell you if you are getting a new element or not.

Comment: is this a typo? `driver.FindElement` in wait vs `WebDriverManager.Driver.FindElement` or it's just because they are in different classes

Comment: @GaurangShah it's a typo. It means the same object. I'll fix it now

Comment: @CodingKuma You were right. Looks like element is destroyed during its assertion because form is refreshing. 
How is it possible to overcome such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since you confirmed the containing element is being destroyed and recreated I can better help. You should be able to just use the "TextToBePresentInElementLocated" instead. This takes a By object instead of the element itself.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.Id("Stage_label"), "SQL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CodingKuma suggested the form is refreshing during value update and element disappears from DOM. 
So it required to wait until element is stalled and then wait for element to appear.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Stage_label"))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(element, "SQL"));
```